Netplan error: device (wg0): linklocal6: failed to get interface identifier; IPv6 cannot continue
How to define a link-local network interface in netplan on a wireguard tunnel (interface)?
When i define a wireguard tunnel using netplan with NetworkManager backend, i get the following errors in system journal:
device (wg0): linklocal6: failed to get interface identifier; IPv6 cannot continue
NetworkManager is a prereq since cockpit properly works only with NetworkMangaer backend (e.g. update checks).
